# Jquery toggle and add/remove

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have two buttons.

Both buttons have a rollover css color change.

One of the buttons just links to another page.. however, the other button when clicked needs to 
A.) Show a hidden div
B.) toggle to the roll-over color and stay that color.  (but not change the other buttons class)

I only want the button with the id of "edit" to toggle the class m-button-regular to m-button-active and not the other button.  The JQuery I am using changes both buttons classes to m-button-active.

What is going wrong in this script?

```
            <a href="#tab1" id="edit" >
            <span class="m-button-small m-button-regular   text-center floatleft clearfix mtm mls" id="sm-tab1">
                <i class="fa fa-gear"></i>
                <p>EDIT</p>
            </span>  
            </a>   
            <a href="#tab1">
            <span class="m-button-small m-button-regular  text-center floatleft clearfix mtm mls" id="sm-tab1">
                <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
                <p>ADD</p>
            </span>  
            </a>  
<div class="row editcontainer">

</div>


$('.editcontainer').hide();
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#edit').click(function(){        
        $(".editcontainer").toggle();
        $('.m-button-regular').toggleClass("m-button-active");
    });

});
```

Comment: I don't know. What's going right? We can't tell - what **is** happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) to refer its child span, then you can use toggle.

> Get the descendants of each element in the current set of matched elements, filtered by a selector, jQuery object, or element.

*Use*

```
$(this).find('.m-button-regular').toggleClass("m-button-active");
```

*instead of*

```
$('.m-button-regular').toggleClass("m-button-active");
```

Answer (score 2):

This seems to do what you want :

```js
$('.editcontainer').hide();
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#edit').click(function() {
    $(".editcontainer").toggle();
    $('#edit').toggleClass("m-button-active");
  });

});
```

```css
.m-button-active {
    color : green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#tab1" id="edit">
  <span class="m-button-small m-button-regular   text-center floatleft clearfix mtm mls" id="sm-tab1">
                <i class="fa fa-gear"></i>
                <p>EDIT</p>
            </span> 
</a>
<a href="#tab1">
  <span class="m-button-small m-button-regular  text-center floatleft clearfix mtm mls" id="sm-tab1">
                <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
                <p>ADD</p>
            </span> 
</a>
<div class="row editcontainer" style="display: none">Edit container</div>
```

By the way your selector was originally selecting both buttons.

Comment: This wasn't working for me.  Perhaps because of the way my CSS is set up.

Comment: Well, I wrote a working snippet based on what you posted in your question. I can't guess the rest of your code, pal :-)

Comment: And I appreciate it.  But it didn't work.  I think the reason why as I look at it is because I needed remove the class m-button-regular and swap it with m-button-active for that button.  Your code simply added the class m-button-active which just added green text.  It did not switch out the classes.

Answer (score 1):

This is refering to all classes:

```
$('.m-button-regular').toggleClass("m-button-active");
```

You must refer the button

```
$("#edit").toggleClass("m-button-active");
```

Answer (score 1):

You are almost right but slight change to your code and bingo

```
$('.editcontainer').hide();
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#edit').click(function(){        
        $(".editcontainer").toggle();
        $('.m-button-regular',this).toggleClass("m-button-active"); //<--- add a scope, same as $(this).find
    });
```

});